# MAPI using Java - What datatype to pass for PWSTR?

Tags: java, c++, unicode, utf, mapi

I want to use MAPISendMailW in Java. The function requires a MapiMessageW structure which I defined in my Java Code. The C++ code from the documentation looks like this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh707273(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
typedef struct {
  ULONG            ulReserved;
  PWSTR            lpszSubject;
  PWSTR            lpszNoteText;
  PWSTR            lpszMessageType;
  PWSTR            lpszDateReceived;
  PWSTR            lpszConversationID;
  FLAGS            flFlags;
  lpMapiRecipDescW lpOriginator;
  ULONG            nRecipCount;
  lpMapiRecipDescW lpRecips;
  ULONG            nFileCount;
  lpMapiFileDescW  lpFiles;
} MapiMessageW, *lpMapiMessageW;
```

The PWSTR is defined as a pointer to a String of 16-Bit Unicode characters (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx#PWSTR).

The String I want to pass as e.g. the lpszSubject includes Unicode characters - for example String myString = "sentence with a č". From my understanding Java uses UTF-16 for Strings. But when I try to pass myString just as the String that it is, it only displays garbage in the mail.
The same happens when I try to get the bytes first from the String and then send **new String(subjectBytes, "UTF-16"))**.

What is the correct datatype on the java side to pass for the PWSTR values?

**EDIT**: as requested in the comments - the jave code

This is where I defined my MapiMessageW:

```
class MapiMessageW extends Structure {
        public NativeLong ulReserved;
        public String lpszSubject;
        public String lpszNoteText;
        public String lpszMessageType;
        public String lpszDateReceived;
        public String lpszConversationID;
        public NativeLong flFlags;
        public Pointer lpOriginator;
        public NativeLong nRecipCount;
        public MapiRecipDescWs lpRecips;
        public NativeLong nFileCount;
        public MapiFileDescWs lpFiles;

        [...]
}
```

Filling in the values here - getSubject() and getBody() both return a String:

```
MapiMessageW message = new MapiMessageW();
message.lpszSubject = new String(email.getSubject());
message.lpszNoteText = new String(email.getBody());
message.nRecipCount = new NativeLong(recipDescs.size());
message.lpRecips = new MapiRecipDescWs(recipDescs);
message.nFileCount = new NativeLong(fileDescs.size());
message.lpFiles = new MapiFileDescWs(fileDescs);
```

Calling MapiSendMailW here, with the message as parameter:

```
rc = Mapi32W.INSTANCE.MAPISendMailW(sessionPtr.getValue(), null, message,
        new NativeLong(Mapi32W.MAPI_DIALOG | Mapi32W.MAPI_LOGON_UI), null).longValue();
```

Comment: `PWSTR` is a `wchar_t*`, where `wchar_t` is 2 bytes on Windows (UTF-16). Since Java strings use UTF-16, there is no conversion needed at all. Just use the Java string data as-is. If you are having trouble with it, you must not be passing the data correctly. Please [edit] your question to show your actual Java code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I added the Java code to the post ... so I send the subject and body as a String but when the mail opens I mostly see question marks

Comment: Win32's `ULONG` is 4 bytes in size, but Java's `Long` is 8 bytes. Also, using `new String` with `String` input is redundant. And question marks usually imply a charset encoding issue.

Comment: @RemyLebeau "And question marks usually imply a charset encoding issue" - I am not sure I understand correctly; if my Java String is UTF-16 encoded and it can be passed as-is to PWSTR, then what could be the encoding issue here?

Comment: First, fix your `ULONG` issue. You very well might be passing a bad structure to `MapiSendMailW()`, causing it to see invalid `PWSTR` pointers due to field offset mismatches. After that, any remaining encoding issue will not be on your end, it would be inside of `MailSendMailW()` itself when it is encoding the email. If it uses a charset that can't handle the Unicode characters you are trying to send, that can cause the question marks. Try specifying the `MAPI_FORCE_UNICODE` flag when calling `MapiSendMailW()`.

Comment: Well the value I pass for the ULONG values is not a Java Long or long but actually a `com.sun.jna.NativeLong` - that works fine. 
I now pass the PWSTR values as a `WString` (also JNA) and it now displays my subject, body and such correctly (before I only saw a line of "???"), except the unicode characters are sill displayed as question marks.
I tried to set the `MAPI_FORCE_UNICODE` flag but it returned with `MAPI_E_UNICODE_NOT_SUPPORTED` (rc 27). As I cannot find any further information about that return code I am wondering what exactly does not support unicode here?

Comment: Ok, FYI I just tried the same thing with Outlook and it worked - everything was displayed correctly. The problem seems to be some Thunderbird config. Anyways, @RemyLebeau Thanks for your help!